# How to get absolute value from animated value in react native?

Tags: reactjs, animation, native, absolute

Let's suppose I have an animated value **pan.y** which is equal to -3.  How can I get the absolute value from -3, which is 3.

I tried **Animated.modulos(pan.y, 1)** and it didn't work. I do not know why there is a second argument in this function.

Like it says in the docs:

> static modulo(a, modulus)
>
> Creates a new Animated value that is the (non-negative) modulo of the
> provided Animated value

here is the link:

> https://reactnative.dev/docs/animated#modulo

Answer (score 2):

It's a bit late, but I also needed to take the `abs` of an `Animated.Value` in order to implement `max` between 2 `Animated.Value`s so hopefully this helps anyone else who is trying to do this.

To give more context on the question, the reason why `Animated.modulus` doesn't work here is since the `modulus` is equivalent of `x % y`. For example, `-2.3 % 1` = 0.7 (so although this value is positive, it doesn't give you what you need.

The general idea on calculating the `abs` value of an `Animated.Value` is taking some value `a` and it's negation `-a`, and clamping them between `0` and `inf`. This way, you'll end up with two values that is the absolute value and `0`. Then you can simply add them.

It looks like this:

```js
function abs(a) {
  const b = Animated.multiply(a, -1);
  const clampedA = Animated.diffClamp(a, 0, Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER);
  const clampedB = Animated.diffClamp(b, 0, Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER);

  return Animated.add(clampedA, clampedB);
};
```

With absolute value, then it's easy to implement both `max` and `min` functions with: `max(r,s) = 0.5 * (r + s + |r-s|)` and `min(r,s) = 0.5 * (r + s - |r-s|)`.

The equivalent javascript code (where `abs` is the method above):

```js
function max(a, b) {
  return Animated.multiply(
    0.5,
    Animated.add(Animated.add(a, b), abs(Animated.subtract(a, b)))
  );
};

function min(a, b) {
  return Animated.multiply(
    0.5,
    Animated.subtract(Animated.add(a, b), abs(Animated.subtract(a, b)))
  );
};
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer. However, when I tried using it, I had to use `interpolate` instead of `diffClamp` for calculating `clampedA/clampedB`, e.g.: `const clampedA = a.interpolate({inputRange: [0, 1], outputRange: [0, 1], extrapolateLeft: "clamp"});`.
```

Answer (score 0):

If the range of your value is finite and known, you can also use `interpolate` to get the absolute value. For example, to get the absolute value of `a` given that it's always between `[-120, 120]`:

```
a.interpolate({
    inputRange: [-120, 0, 120],
    outputRange: [120, 0, 120]
})
```

Answer (score -1):

In javascript you can use Math.abs but I am not sure if it will work

Comment: Math.abs does not work on an animated value I think it must be one of these functions "add, subtract, modulo, divide" but I do not know how to do this